# how to return customize data in prisma subscription

Tags: graphql, prisma

I am learning graphql & prisma and I came across a question on prisma subscription.

I want to return an item list whenever there is a creation or update on Item. So this is my code which not works.

scheme.graphql

```
# import Item from "./generated/prisma.graphql"

type Subscription {
    todoItems: TodoItems
}

type TodoItems {
    items: [Item!]!
}
```

resolver

```
const Subscription = {
    todoItems: {
        subscribe: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
            const itemSubscription = await context.db.subscription.item({
                where: { mutation_in: ['CREATED', 'UPDATED'] },
            }, info);

            return itemSubscription;
        },
        resolve: async (payload, args, context, info) => {
            const items = await context.db.query.items({ type: 0, orderBy: 'updatedAt_DESC' }, info);
            return { items };
        },
    },
}

module.exports = {
    Subscription,
}
```

and in graphql playground,

```
subscription{
  todoItems{
    items{
      title
    }
  }
}
```

it gives the error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Anonymous Subscription must select only one top level field.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "todoItems"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "stacktrace": [
            "Error: Anonymous Subscription must select only one top level field.",
            "    at asErrorInstance (d:\\git\\inote\\node_modules\\graphql\\execution\\execute.js:489:43)",
            "    at <anonymous>",
            "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prisma does not support subscribing item lists. Instead, prisma wants you to subscribe to single item mutations ("created", "updated", "deleted"). As described [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/prisma-api/subscriptions-aey0vohche#type-subscriptions).

E.g.

```
subscription newTodos {
  todo(where: {
    mutation_in: [CREATED]
  }) {
    mutation
    node {
      title
    }
  }
}
```

To get "the full list", you have to query on the todos **after** subscribing to avoid missing events (race condition). As a result you have to manually "sync" the data from the subscription and your query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just want to share [this](https://www.prisma.io/tutorials/build-a-realtime-graphql-server-with-subscriptions-ct11/) tutorial as a **thorough intro to implementing subscriptions with Prisma**.